# verify that either attributes has a value defined and is different from "nil" with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid

I have a model `Post` with 2 attributes:

`attr1` and `attr2`

I want check that either attributes have a value defined or are different from "nil".

How can I do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this problem is the next query:

```
Post.any_of({ :attr1.ne => nil }, { :attr2.ne => nil})
```

Thank you very much!. Regards!